# VBA - Call a module to brings a string and complete Query

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, database-connection

quite new to VBA. I tried to fix this problem by my own but any of the open threats seems to fit in what I need.

**Context:**
I have this Macro that brings info from a DDBB and copies it in a new Workbook. I would like to organize different queries in different modules than the main one and call them on demand.

**Problem:** 
I have set my query in a new module as a string, but I get ByRef or Method or data member not found all the time:

*Main Sub*

```
Sub Consulta_Sql_ERP()

'Declare variables
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ws2 As Workbook
    Dim iCols As Integer


'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
                                  Data Source=(...);
                                  Initial Catalog=(...);
                                  User ID=(...);
                                  Password=(...);
                                  Persist Security Info=True;"
    objMyConn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'

        strSQL = Module4.Querys(Query1)

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Open a NewWorkbook
    Call NewBook

'Copy Data to the new book
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook
        ws2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Copy headers
    For iCols = 0 To objMyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
    objMyConn.Close

'Close and save
    Call carpetaventas
    'ws.SaveAs Savechanges:=True, Filename:="" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    'ws2.Close Savechanges:=True, Filename:="" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd"), 
    'RouteWorkbook:="C:\Ventas"    
End Sub
```

The module in which I have the String of my query is "Module4"

*Sub in which I have my Query:*

```
Sub Queries(Query1 As String)
Set Query1 = "Select * from table1"
End Sub
```

It works if I directly introduce the Query after "strSQL" but not if I "call" the Sub on Module4. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't use Set when assigning a string - that's for Object-type variables

Comment: Query1 = "Select * from table1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strSQL = Module4.Query1()


Function Query1() As String
    Query1 = "Select * from table1"
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tim Williams small typo in function call/return.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! :) I didn't know that I could structure a Function that way. My intention was to "call" the object that I was creating in Module 4 by first calling the "Sub" Something that I learn today! :)